# How can I configure RDS Mysql password, in case it is stored in AWS secret manager?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

This is my code, any help would be appreciated, thank you

```
<?php
define('HOST', "rdjxgve3dr5txt.cnn3hxxbkiiq.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com");
define('DBUSER', "Admin");
define('PASS', ".??????????");
define('DB', "myexample");
define('PORT', 3306);

$link=mysqli_connect(HOST,DBUSER,PASS,DB,PORT);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)){
    echo "Failure to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in you application you would use **AWS PHP SDK** to get the password from the Secret Manager using [getSecretValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-secretsmanager-2017-10-17.html#getsecretvalue).

Once obtained you would probably need to **cache** it somewhere as not to query the manager for every single request. To access the secret manger from your instance, you would also need an **instance role** with necessary permissions.

Comment: Here is a blog from [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/) on using the Secrets Manager along with RDS. Also, the problem with caching is that if for some reason if the RDS password is changed, then the application fails to connect to the DB. Not sure of the best way, but one way is to specify the cache duration.